# Unable to start queue manger on DR node after rsync

Tags: ibm-mq

While setting up MQ v 8.0.0.11 on DR node , everything works fine. But after I run the rsync from PROD to sync DR, queue managers are not coming up and getting below error :

```
-bash-4.2$ strmqm DTEQM
WebSphere MQ queue manager 'DTEQM' starting.
The queue manager is associated with installation 'Installation1'.
AMQ7017: Log not available.
```

Files which are getting synced are below:

```
/etc/hosts
/etc/passwd
/etc/group
/etc/shadow
/etc/sudoers
/etc/services
/var/spool/cron/
/usr/local/appseng/
/uscripts/
/home/
/var/mqm/log/*
/var/mqm/qmgrs/*
```

errors from QM logs :

Log replay was not happening.

```
07/04/2019 01:12:08 AM - Process(53309.4) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuc0)
                    Host(clprvldtemqa01.dataphile.broadridge.com) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.11) QMgr(DTEQM)

AMQ5051: The queue manager task 'LOGGER-IO' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The critical utility task manager has started the LOGGER-IO task. This task has
now started 1 times.
ACTION:
None.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
07/04/2019 01:12:08 AM - Process(53309.1) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuc0)
                    Host(clprvldtemqa01.dataphile.broadridge.com) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.11) QMgr(DTEQM)

AMQ5041: The queue manager task 'LOGGER-IO' has ended.

EXPLANATION:
The queue manager task LOGGER-IO has ended.
ACTION:
None.
```

Please suggest.

FDCs created as below :

```
| Date/Time         :- Thu July 04 2019 01:11:41 EDT                          |
| UTC Time          :- 1562217101.209709                                      |
| UTC Time Offset   :- -240 (EST)                                             |
| Host Name         :- clprvldtemqa01.dataphile.broadridge.com                |
| Operating System  :- Linux 3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64                       |
| PIDS              :- 5724H7251                                              |
| LVLS              :- 8.0.0.11                                               |
| Product Long Name :- WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)               |
| Vendor            :- IBM                                                    |
| O/S Registered    :- 1                                                      |
| Data Path         :- /var/mqm                                               |
| Installation Path :- /opt/mqm                                               |
| Installation Name :- Installation1    (1)                                   |
| License Type      :- Production                                             |
| Probe Id          :- HL080077                                               |
| Application Name  :- MQM                                                    |
| Component         :- mqlOpenLogExtent                                       |
| SCCS Info         :- /build/slot1/p800_P/src/lib/logger/amqherr0.c,         |
| Line Number       :- 118                                                    |
| Build Date        :- Dec 14 2018                                            |
| Build Level       :- p800-011-181212.1                                      |
| Build Type        :- IKAP - (Production)                                    |
| Effective UserID  :- 179 (mqm)                                              |
| Real UserID       :- 179 (mqm)                                              |
| Program Name      :- amqzmuc0                                               |
| Arguments         :- -m DTEQM                                               |
| Addressing mode   :- 64-bit                                                 |
| LANG              :- en_US.UTF-8                                            |
| Process           :- 53273                                                  |
| Process(Thread)   :- 53276                                                  |
| Thread            :- 4    LoggerIO                                          |
| QueueManager      :- DTEQM                                                  |
| UserApp           :- FALSE                                                  |
| ConnId(1) IPCC    :- 4                                                      |
| ConnId(2) QM      :- 4                                                      |
| Last HQC          :- 2.0.0-686400                                           |
| Last HSHMEMB      :- 2.9.9-2538048                                          |
| Last ObjectName   :-                                                        |
| Major Errorcode   :- hrcE_MQLP_EXT_DBID_INCORR                              |
| Minor Errorcode   :- OK                                                     |
| Probe Type        :- INCORROUT                                              |
| Probe Severity    :- 2                                                      |
| Probe Description :- AMQ6125: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred.  |
```

Comment: Are these the queue managers on PROD or DR that won't come up?

Comment: Did your run rsync while prod was running?

Comment: @Morag , queue manager not coming up on DR after I run rsync from prod server

Comment: @JoshMc rsync is on prod, so prod env is all up and running. While I had run rsync from prod ,DR was down. So after rsync, I tried to bring up queue manager on DR, it was not coming up

Comment: This is likely why.   If prod was down it would probably work.   You could also look at using linear logs and coping those over to dr, you can run dr in a mode that it just plays the logs to keep dr in sync with prod.   You could also look at 9.1's new RDQM HA configuration.

Comment: Never take a backup of a queue manager when it is running.  Stop the PROD queue manager, run rsync then start the DR queue manager.

Comment: Piyali, Did you figure out this issue?